# Поменять текст кнопки ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button

В кнопке "отправить" поменять текст на "отправлено" и деактивировать кнопку.
Это не проблема сделать через .html, но у меня несколько таких форм. Как сделать это именно для данной кнопки

Пример формы (таких 5 штук на сайте)

```js
$("form#data").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'sender.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function success(data) {

    },
    error: function error(data) {
      console.log('error sending');
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
      <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
      <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
    </div>
    <label class="file-label">
                                <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple="">Прикрепить резюме
                            </label>
    <div class="note">
      <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p><a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если отправка успешна то кнопка блокируется навсегда, если отправка не удалась, текст меняется на "Отправить", и кнопка разблокируется.

```js
$("form#data").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var btn = $(this).find('.btn--accent');
  btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Отправлено');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'sender.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function success(data) {

    },
    error: function error(data) {
      console.log('error sending');
      btn.removeAttr('disabled').text('Отправить');
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="job-form vacancies-form" id="data" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <div class="title">
    <p>Запишитесь на собеседование</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Имя</span>
      <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div class="input-wrap"><span class="input-title">Номер телефона</span>
      <input class="form-input phone" type="text" placeholder="" name="phone">
    </div>
    <label class="file-label">
                                <input class="file-upload" type="file" placeholder="Прикрепить резюме" name="file[]" value="1" size="40" multiple="">Прикрепить резюме
                            </label>
    <div class="note">
      <p class="text">Отправляя это сообщение, вы соглашаетесь с </p><a class="link" href="https://klinikajemchujnaya.ru/politika-obrabotki-personalnykh-dannykh" target="_blank">политикой конфиденциальности</a>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-md btn btn--accent" type="submit"><span class="btn__text">Отправить</span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```